AnyConnect does not allow local LAN access
I'm trying to use Cisco AnyConnect to connect to a corporate VPN.
Inside the profile XML config file, I can see <LocalLanAccess UserControllable="true">false</LocalLanAccess>
I check the Allow local LAN acces when using VPN if configured checkbox in the preferences tab to no avail.
When I change the config file to true, it simply overwrites back to false when the VPN connects.
I can't use OpenConnect because the VPN relies on Cisco Secure Desktop for auth.
